# string subscript out of range c++

Tags: c++, error-handling

I need a help in a very basic c++ code.
My program is about guessing name game the problem which i faced is in reading string char by char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void Play(int, int,int, string[], string[]);
string GetRandomName(int, int, int , string[], string[]);
const int ArrayMax = 100;



void Play(int selection, int FArraySize, int  MArraySize,string Female[], string Male[])

        {
            int MAX_TRIES = 3;
            int i=0;
            ofstream ofFile;
            ifstream InFile;
            int num_of_wrong_guesses=0;
            char letter;
            string GuessedName;
            GuessedName = GetRandomName(selection, FArraySize, MArraySize, Female, Male);

            cout << "Guess the following name:" << endl;

            while (GuessedName[i]!= 0 ){
                cout<<"?";
                i++;
            }

            cout << "\nEnter a guess letter? or * to enter the entire name" << endl;
            cin >> letter;

            return;
        }
```

I don't complete coding...

the problem is in the while loop how can i solve it without using cstring?
could you help me?

Comment: So what is your problem? Compilation error (which)? Wrong output (what is the output and what the expected)? Program crash?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `string[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

while(GuessedName[i] != 0)
{
    cout << "?";
    i++;
}
```

Seems like you are trying to print sequence of `?` with the length of the string to guess. But you cannot treat `std::string` as c-string. When its length is `n`, `GuessedName[n]` is string subscript out of range - you cannot access one element past end - it's not null-terminated. Use for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < GuessedName.length(); ++i)
    cout << "?";
```

Or simply:

```
cout << std::string(GuessedName.length(), '?');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the while loop like this:

```
        while (GuessedName[i]){
            cout<<"?";
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: This does not change program's logic by any means.

Comment: did the for loop method of LogicStuff work? it should work...if the problem is what you think it is...